# Extracting CSV files from access table based on unique field using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am having an access table with various fields and thousand of records. 1st field in table is mobile number which is having duplicate records However corresponding other fields are unique. What I want that basis all similar mobile number in 1st field should be exported to new CSV file with corresponding records. Sample file and out put is depicted below. Kindly help me with VBA code in access. Having trouble in decoding it. Any help would be appreciated.

Access Table:

```
Field1 Field2 Field3 Field4
AAA    VGB     GHT   GBH
CCC    FGT     BDE   NHG
AAA    GGT     BNF   NFR
AAA    BGF     MKJ   GFT
CCC    VFD     NHJ   NGF
```

Output of this should be 2 CSV files with name of unique mobile number. Out out is shown below

CSV File 1 (AAA);

```
Field1 Field2 Field3 Field 4
AAA    VGB    GHT    GBH
AAA    GGT    BNF    NFR
AAA    BGF    MKJ    GFT
```

CSV File 2 (CCC)

```
Field1 Field2 Field3 Field4
CCC    FGT    BDE    NHG
CCC    VFD    NHJ    NGF
```

Comment: and when field1 = BBB, do you want to create a BBB file? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Without seeing the code you are having problems with, it is going to be hard for us to help you "decode" it.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to do this with SQL and output the results to CSV (Query, Results To, File/Text).  This can then be automated using VBA if you need to.
The SQL might be something like
SELECT
    *
FROM
    YourTable
ORDER BY
    Field1

This would go into one file you could then chop up when the Field1 value changes.

To be a bit fancier, you could use a cursor around the select, fetch the Field1 value from it say into a variable @Field1 and use to output into individual files.

SELECT
    *
FROM
    YourTable
WHERE
    Field1 = @Field1

Cursor example here: 
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/277847/How-to-use-Cursor-in-Sql